# Manually transitioning from FSSM to Listen gems for Sass?

Tags: rubygems, sass, compass-sass

Hi: I'm trying to do the beginner's tutorial on Sass at http://thesassway.com/beginner/getting-started-with-sass-and-compass.  When I coded 'compass watch sass-test' in the command line I got this message from the developer of FSSM:
    "Dear developers making use of FSSM in your project , FSSM is essentially dead at this     point.  Further development will be taking place in the shared guard/listen project.  please let us know if you need help transitioning"--Travis Tilley

I found one file that had FSSM, which was 'watch_project.rb' under "commands" file, and tried to change out all the instances of fssm or FSSM to listen or even LISTEN, and got many error messages--

```
`C:\RailsInstaller>compass watch sass-test --trace
NameError on line ["81"] of C: undefined local variable or method `listen' for #
<Compass::Commands::WatchProject:0x29ee858>
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compas
s/commands/base.rb:18:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compas
s/commands/project_base.rb:19:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compas
s/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:43:in `perform!'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compas
s/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in `run!'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compas
s:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

and so on....

Any ideas as how to make the transition into 'listen' and get rid of FSSM? I did see the changelog for Sass and the issue is under Deprecation for FSSM in item 3.1.16, and that they were transitioning from FSSM to Listen, but it doesn't tell you how to do it.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Vegasvikk

Answer (score 0):

This message is directed to sass developers. You do not have to do anything.